# Discrete Fourier transform for musical analysis

Tags: fourier, music, calculus

I am a senior in highschool and am currently trying to conduct an exploration on Fourier analysis, specifically using the discrete Fourier transform to analyze a chord played on my piano. Basically I'd play a chord of 3 notes, deduce the different frequencies of the sound wave, and estimate the chord played.

I am having issues trying to come up with theory to the Fourier transform, including related math concepts, derivation of the formula, and key math that needs to be understood in order to use the fourier transform. Is there any way someone could help with that as I am a bit unfamiliar with this.

Comment: you can read this excellent book online for free : http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm

Answer (score 0):

**(1) Respect**

I really respect your self-learning mindset!

**(2) Literatur**

FFT/DFT is well understood, used in many different applications and therefore well documented in form of literature. You basically can not do a Physics/Engineering undergrad without it.

**(3) Sources**

A [quick intro into FFT](https://www.montana.edu/rmaher/ee477_sp07/lecture/EE477_SP07_fft_intro.pdf)

A [elementary intro](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2019/REUPapers/Bounchaleun.pdf)

[More detailed](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Edls/Expository/2014-10-FFT.pdf)

[Fixed-point FFT optimization](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN2114.pdf)

[Stanford lecture series on youtube! FOR FREE!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZNm7L96pfY&list=PLB24BC7956EE040CD)